# Cell change to a range of 4 colours based on 4 manual value changes value in a different cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

CONDITIONAL FORMATTING (IF AND)??

I would like to type a name in `column C` and have it change to one of 4 colours (*BLUE*, *RED*, *GREEN*, *YELLOW*) based on a series of manually inserted appointment abbreviations in `column D`.

```
 C               D 

Marc            T1
William         T2
Bryan           T3
Gary            CIED
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but most likely you'll need to set four separate rules. You can set only one type of formatting per rule.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select cell `C1`
2. Click in the menu *Conditional Formatting* and select *Manage Rules*.
3. It will look like this:

[image: empty rules manager]

4. Press The button New Rule and you will find this:

[image: New Formatting Rule]

5. Now you have to put in the box `=D1="T1"` and in the preview you have to choose the format that you want (blue font for example) and click OK.
6. Repeat for the other 3 formats and at the end you will have this:

[image]

7. Copy format from the cell C1 to the other cells using the Format Painter.
   [image]

Comment: As you mentioned I don't think I explained it that well.. The end state is that when I type either T1 , T2,T3, or CIED in column D then both column D and column C will change to the respective colours. In the event that I change my mind and delete T1,T2,T3 or CIED then I want both columns to revert to neutral .  The formulas you provided have been helpful and have got me thinking but I cannot quite get it right

Comment: You can repeat the same procedure for column D.